# How can I get multiple lines in a Description Tag?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a gun I'd like to name "xxx" with a Name Tag, which is fine.

However, the description I'd like to use is:

```
"xxxx,
xxxxx"
```

Is there any way to get two separate lines using a description tag, and if so, how?

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe it runs with some crappy text command like <br> or /n? :p

Comment: @user1337 I don't want to waste a nametag, only to find it out whether it works or not

Comment: I can't say for certain, but the only way to obtain it would be with formatting commands like user1137 suggested, and the game almost surely renders these tags useless to prevent glitching.

Comment: When you use the description tag, it gives a preview of what the text will look like, this way you can possibly check for results. Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUktuBbtvkQ) for proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly,no.
You can simulaue the effect by putting like twenty        s after the first line and use word wrapping!

Comment: What key are you talking about? or are you talking about the Space bar?